# Benefits of Polling Multiple Ble connections vs simultaneous connections?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Say I have a BLE device that is both a server(has info) and a peripheral(needs to access outside info), that upon receiving or generating it's own data has to share with other Server/Peripherals in it's vicinity.

Would it be beneficial that I only attempt to connect to the devices through BLE when their is data to be transfered "even though it periodically connects to each server sequentially to see if it can" or would it be better to keep connections simultaneously use callbacks to determine when connected and simply transfer data when required to(through from what i understand the devices that I use can only process on gatt operation at a time meaning having 4 connections to quickly transfer data is irrelevant).

**In other words** is it beneficial to continually reconnect and disconnect a peripheral and server or simply have a connection to as many servers as I need(even though apparently I can only perform one gatt operation at a time i.e 1 characteristic read/wright).

balanced requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, instead of reading to see if there's data available, I would stay in connection with the devices and have them use Bluetooth notifications to communicate data when it becomes available.

Alternatively you could consider having the Peripherals advertise only when they have data to invite the Central mode device to connect. It would need to be periodically scanning to detect this however.

Advantages/disadvantages depend on your priorities and the nature of the two types of device.

FYI you're mixing terminology a little btw. When discovering devices you have a GAP Peripheral which advertises and a GAP Central which scans. After the Central connects to the Peripheral connect you have a GATT Client and a GATT Server. Usually the GAP Peripheral becomes the GATT Server but it does not need to be this way. The GAP Peripheral can just as easily become the GATT Client. It's the GATT Server that has the state data in an attribute table in the form of Services, Characteristics and Descriptors.

Comment: May I also ask if it is possible to advertise and scan while being connected to a device, currently the project incorporates a state machine for advertising, scanning and connecting; though the GATT server is separate.

Comment: It depends on the stack you're using. Bluetooth 4.1 made this possible but I believe support for concurrent GAP central and peripheral roles is optional. So I recommend checking the spec of the stack you're using or just trying a quick prototype to see if it works.